# Update a column from a complex query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

So I have this query:

```
SELECT 
    [ProductInstance].ProductInstanceID, 
    [ProductInstance].Name,
```

> I have deleted this code because I have now been told I can't show it here and it is not possible to delete the whole question.

The platformid of all these productinstances have null value. I want to update the platformid of all instances in the query above that have [ProductInstance].Name begining with a 'AAA'

How can I do this the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try. Based on your explanation, this should work. Replace 'some value' with what you want to update `PlatformID` to.

```
UPDATE PI
  SET
      PlatformID = 'some value'
FROM [ITOrder].[dbo].[ProductInstance] PI
     INNER JOIN [Product] ON [Product].ProductID = PI.ProductID
     INNER JOIN ProductPlacement ON ProductPlacement.ProductInstanceID = PI.ProductInstanceID
WHERE [Product].CategoryID IN(39, 40)
AND ProductPlacement.FK_StatusID = 8
AND PI.PlatformID IS NULL
AND LEFT(PI.Name, 3) = 'AAA';
```

Answer (score 1):

I would write the query like this:

```
UPDATE pi
    SETPlatformId = ?
    FROM ITOrder.dbo.ProductInstance pi JOIN
         Product p
         ON p.ProductID = pi.ProductID JOIN
         ProductPlacement pp
         ON pp.ProductInstanceID = pi.ProductInstanceID
    WHERE p.CategoryID IN (39, 40) AND
          pp.FK_StatusID = 8 AND
          pi.PlatformID IS NULL AND
          pi.Name LIKE 'AAA%';
```

The `?` is for the value you want.

Summary of changes:

- introduces table aliases so the query is easier to read and write
- uses `in` instead of a chain of `or` conditions
- uses `like` for the `Name` comparison (this allows the use of indexes)
- changes `==` to `=` (the latter is the standard equality comparison operator)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the like statement at the end as below

```
UPDATE PI
  SET
      PI.PlatformID = 'some value'
FROM [ITOrder].[dbo].[ProductInstance] PI
     INNER JOIN [Product] ON [Product].ProductID = PI.ProductID
     INNER JOIN ProductPlacement ON ProductPlacement.ProductInstanceID = PI.ProductInstanceID
WHERE([Product].CategoryID = 39
      OR [Product].CategoryID = 40)
     AND ProductPlacement.FK_StatusID = 8
     AND [ProductInstance].PlatformID IS NULL
     AND [ProductInstance].Name LIKE 'AAA%';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE ProductInstance
  SET
      **PI.PlatformID = 'value'**   
FROM [ITOrder].[dbo].[ProductInstance] ProductInstance
     INNER JOIN [Product] ON [Product].ProductID = ProductInstance.ProductID
     INNER JOIN ProductPlacement ON ProductPlacement.ProductInstanceID = PI.ProductInstanceID
WHERE([Product].CategoryID = 39
      OR [Product].CategoryID = 40)
     AND ProductPlacement.FK_StatusID = 8
     AND [ProductInstance].PlatformID IS NULL
     **AND [ProductInstance].Name LIKE 'AAA%';**
```